# ZTE Modem not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, software-installation, 18.04, usb-modem

I have run the command *lsusb* and got the following code:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:055d Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 028: ID 19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It shows the Modem but I can not find it on the network section, even after unmount the 'ZTE USB SCSI CD-ROM (2.31)' device from the disk. What should I do? Or, Can anyone tell me the process of installing modem handler like Windows OS ?

Comment: try to see what is offering the mounted USB CD-ROM, maybe there are some drivers and/or manufacturer software to be installed. in some other ZTE modems there is.

Comment: usbmodems need to be configured like ppp connection. please check in configuration > network.
If you have affinity with the terminal, you can follow this tutorial. https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem with modem ZTE MF112 produced for Russian mobile provider MTS. In Ubuntu 15.10 and in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it is recognized as **19d2:2003 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM**. Now I have partially solved my problem with it. It connects to mobile network and provides Internet, but sometimes it is necessary to unplug and again plug the modem three times for the system to see it. Try to take the following steps:

1. Install the **usb-modeswitch** package if it is not already installed.
2. In the folder  **/usr/share/usb_modeswitch** create a text document with the name **19d2:2000**. Its content should be

   > # ZTE devices
   >   
   >   ReleaseDelay=9000 
   >   
   >   ReleaseDelay=9000 
   >   
   >   TargetVendor= 0x19d2
   >   
   >   TargetProductList="0001,0002,0015,0016,0017,0019,0031,0033,0037,0042,0052,0055,0061,0063,0064,0066,0091,0108,0117,0128,0151,0157,0177,1402,2002,2003"
   >   
   >   StandardEject=1
   >   
   >   MessageContent="55534243123456782000000080000c85010101180101010101000000000000"
3. Edit the file **/etc/usb_modeswitch.conf** and set the option **SetStorageDelay=6** in it. You can also uncomment the line **EnableLogging=1** and then you will see the log file **/var/log/usb_modeswitch.log** with modem errors if they occur.

Comment: Note: The link is in Russian.